# cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left on device

Tags: bash, debian

I have debian on my VPS server and suddenly it stops to work. It says that

```
root@vps-16746:/# cd ~
root@vps-16746:~# mkdir 3
mkdir: cannot create directory `3': No space left on device
```

If I press <kbd>TAB</kbd> I'll get `-bash: cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left on device`. But it seems that I have enough space

```
root@vps-16746:~# df -h
Filesystem                                              Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs                                                   29G  5.0G   22G  19% /
udev                                                     10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs                                                    99M  244K   98M   1% /run
/dev/disk/by-uuid/4546171a-7358-4c50-b66d-c86162f4d52d   29G  5.0G   22G  19% /
tmpfs                                                   5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                                                   299M     0  299M   0% /run/shm
/dev/xvda1                                              194M   24M  160M  13% /boot
```

Any advice?

Comment: Sorry, it is the same problem like https://serverfault.com/questions/739399/bash-cannot-create-temp-file-for-here-document-no-space-left-on-device/739400

Comment: Please edit your question to indicate the reason the answers to the link question do not answer your question

Comment: Try looking at the output of `stat -f /` -- with the `-f` command-line option, it will dump the info on the file system under `/` rather than the directory entry. You'll see whether you have free inodes or not. 
 The `dumpe2fs /` encancation is also of interest for `extN` filesystems but this tool is not installed by default.